# Verilog/SystemVerilog syntax how to use a parameter to indicate the bit streamlength when it is > 32 bits?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have this few code lines in my Verilog/SystemVerilog,

```
parameter DATA_SZ=45;
reg [DATA_SZ-1:0] r_data;
initial r_data = 45'h1F_A4A3A2A1A0;
// How to replace it by 'initial r_data = (DATA_SZ)'h1F_A4A3A2A1A0;?
```

Now how can I make it more scalable by replace 45 by DATA_SZ?
Looks like it fails the syntax. Could anybody suggest some good method?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this. You can just write

```
initial r_data = 'h1F_A4A3A2A1A0;
```

And the literal will be implicitly 0 padded on the right before being assigned to `r_data`. If you want to be pedantic, you can write an explicit cast

```
initial r_data = DATA_SZ'('h1F_A4A3A2A1A0);
```

Comment: Hi Dave, both method has the issue of 'bit overflow during conversion from text'. Basically it only assigns 32 bits in this case being 00_00A3A2A1A0. It works if I put directly r_data = 45'h1F_A4A3A2A1A0, then all bits are assigned.